# How to create Eclipse project with EGit clone

Tags: eclipse, egit, gitolite, gitlab

After spending a decade with SVN I've finally taken the plunge with Git. I have set up Git, Gitolite and GitLab on a server and have successfully added code to my local repository, committed, cloned repositories and pushed code back to repositories. So far, so good. Now enters EGit...

I have cloned a repository using the Git Repository Exploring view using the following syntax for the path:

```
ssh://dexter:vaultanalyser.git
```

(In GitLab, repositories are referred to as projects, so I *assume* that I am supposed to have one repository per Eclipse project? Rather than a SVN-style single parent repository that contains multiple projects?)

This imports the repository into:

```
/Users/mattpainter/git/vaultanalyser
```

I was expecting this step to automatically create an Eclipse project for me with **all the source**, but this isn't so. I tried fudging the target directory so it's in my workspace, but this isn't working either.

How do I get the cloned source available within Eclipse? [This site](http://blog.msbbc.co.uk/2009/11/get-eclipse-egit-and-github-all-working.html) implies that if you create a project with the same name as the repository, it all magically works, but this isn't the case (yes, I know the article is about Github, not GitLab, but I figured the two were close enough for the task at hand).

I've then tried creating a project in Eclipse and sharing it - but then the whole project appears as a sub-folder in the repository. If repositories are indeed analogous to projects, this isn't really what I want.

I've looked through other StackOverflow topics that look related, but I fear I'm still missing a key piece of understanding with how this is supposed to work and it's all looking remarkably convoluted thus far.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In GitLab, repositories are referred to as projects, so I assume that I am supposed to have one repository per Eclipse project?

Yes, but a GitLab "project" isn't necessarily an Eclipse one.
It doesn't have to follow an SVN structure, as illustrated in "[Eclipse reference directory outside eclipse project directory but within repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073627/eclipse-reference-directory-outside-eclipse-project-directory-but-within-reposit/7074255#7074255)".

All you need to do is to create an Eclipse project, specifying the source directory being *not* in the default path (Eclipse workspace), but wherever you cloned your repo (as described in "[Getting started with Eclipse + EGit - confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320423/getting-started-with-eclipse-egit-confused)").
That way, the eclipse project you just declared (and referenced in the Eclipse workspace) has its files (`.project` and `.classpath`) at the root of the Git repo.
And Egit can then manage that project just fine.
Or you can import it directly with Egit: "[Eclipse + EGit: clone project into workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396349/eclipse-egit-clone-project-into-workspace/6396416#6396416)".

---

As the [OP nullpainter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1239406/nullpainter) reports below:

> The original issue was compounded by invalid permissions in the `.git/objects` folder on the server.
>   Running a `chmod git:git -R *` on the folder solved the issue

He details the right setup below.

Comment: Thanks; that worked a treat. The thing that tripped me up is that if you choose to share the project, the target location was /Users/mattpainter/git/<git repo name>/<Eclipse project name>, which isn't what I was wanting. With linked source it still displays this but when committing shows both <Eclipse project name>/src/<myfiles> and src/<my files>. Very confusing...!

Comment: Actually, this issue may be because I just created a linked `src` folder pointing at the repo - my version of Eclipse (Juno) doesn't appear to have a 'create project from existing source', which functions as the way you describe.

I currently have `.project` and `.classpath` in my Eclipse workspace, which I suppose is workable.

Comment: Right. The 'create project from existing source' has been amalgamated into the standard 'New Java Project' dialog. When doing this, and 'Use or create repository in parent folder of project' when sharing to avoid errors about conflicting `.project` files, I then get the following error:

`An internal Exception occurred during push: dexter:vaultanalyser.git: Missing tree 32f2fe4f5ee5a4e2e7265ac5068a2b17a30b32e4`

Comment: Ha! After trying once more from the console and encountering an insufficient permission error, I discovered that some directories in the 'objects' folder on the server were owned by root. Changing these made everything happy!

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @VonC's answer, the steps to get EGit and Eclipse to play nicely is:

1. Select 'Clone a Git repository' from EGit, accepting all defaults. This will create a folder in a `git` parent folder, somewhere outside your workspace.
2. Create a new Eclipse project. I'm using Java, but I assume there are similar steps for other languages. On the first dialog, untick 'Use default location' and instead select the repository folder created in step 1. Accept all defaults.
3. Select `Team > Share Project...` from your new project. Select Git, and tick the 'Use or create repository in parent folder of project'.

Now you can push your code and Eclipse dot files to your git repository from within Eclipse.

(My original issue was compounded by invalid permissions in the `.git/objects` folder on the server - running a `chmod git:git -R *` on the folder solved the issues)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback (+1). I have included it in my answer for more visibility

Answer (score 0):

I check it out with the command line - then build my projects on top of that. In fact, I end up doing most operations with command line git. EGit is useful for viewing the diffs but I find command line has more power and control. Git is mostly about giving devs lots of power and control.